# Find the focus of a parabola that touches $x=0$, $y=0$, $x-y+1=0$, and $-2x-y-8=0$.

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

> Find the focus of a parabola that touches $x=0$, $y=0$,
>   $x-y+1=0$, and $-2x-y-8=0$.

I am not getting how to find the equation of parabola from these four tangents.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: I get that the equation of the parabola is $9 x^2+6 x y+y^2+24x-8y+16=0$, but my process was convoluted. Seeking a clever approach.

Comment: Can you send me that approach even @Blue

Comment: Before I invest a lot of effort into documenting my approach ... Please explain what you know about this problem (or these types of problems) and what tools are to be used to solve it. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? ... The source would be nice: is this a textbook exercise? a contest question? What level of sophistication is assumed? ... This information helps answerers tailor responses to best serve you, without duplicating your effort or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Since you have already accepted an answer, there's no need for me to post mine. (Generally, it's good to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer ---at least in the case of a non-obvious question--- to encourage more responses and give people time to gather and/or present their thoughts. But no matter ...) I'd still like to know the source of this problem. Each answer so far has used a keen, and quite distinct, insight; I'm curious about what the author of the question might have had in mind.

Comment: Actually I was not aware of the rule of acceptance @Blue . I will take care from now onwards. The problem was framed by my coaching sir in the test. It's of Class 12th of India, and practice question of IIT Exam, for which success rate is nearly 1 %

Comment: Still, you can add your answer as I have not accepted anyone's answer @Blue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first inclination was to compute an equation of the parabola using essentially [Jan-Magnus Økland’s method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3430748/265466), but the problem posed in the quote block is to find its focus, and this can be done directly, without finding the parabola itself.

The foot of the perpendicular from a parabola’s focus to any tangent line lies on the tangent to its vertex. So, if the coordinates of the focus are $(h,k)$, we know from the fact that the parabola is tangent to the coordinate axes that an equation of this line is $x/h+y/k=1$. Computing the feet of the perpendiculars to the other two tangents and requiring that they lie on this line produces the following system of equations: $${h^2+2hk+k^2+h-k\over2hk}=1 \\ {2h^2-5hk+2k^2+8h+16k\over5hk}=-1$$ with solution $h=-6/5$, $k=2/5$.

If you do need an equation for this parabola, one is easily developed using this focus. We have a pair of perpendicular tangents that intersect at the origin, so we know the directrix passes through the origin. It is also parallel to the vertex tangent found above, so with a little rearrangement we can find the equation $x-3y=0$ for it. Using the formulas for distance to a point and a line, an equation of the parabola is therefore $${(x-3y)^2\over10}=\left(x+\frac65\right)^2+\left(y-\frac25\right)^2.$$ Rearrange as desired.

Comment: Can you explain this statement of your answer,"Computing the feet of the perpendiculars to the other two tangents and requiring that they lie on this line produces the following system of equations", mathematically?

Comment: @AmanGupta Do you know how to produce the equation of a line perpendicular to another that passes through a given point? Do you know how to compute the intersection of two lines? That’s all there is to it, with the minor twist that the coordinates of that point are unknown. It’s basic stuff that I’ve assumed that anyone working at the level of this sort of problem is already fluent with.

Answer (score 1):

The unique conic tangent to five lines can be found by dualizing, taking the usual determinant to find the conic through five points and dualizing back.

Finding the conic through $(1:-1:1),(1/4:1/8:1),(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)$ is to take the determinant

$\begin{pmatrix}
     x^{2}&x\,y&y^{2}&x\,z&y\,z&z^{2}\\
     1&0&0&0&0&0\\
     0&0&1&0&0&0\\
     0&0&0&0&0&1\\
     1&{-1}&1&1&{-1}&1\\
     \frac{1}{16}&\frac{1}{32}&\frac{1}{64}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{8}&1\end{pmatrix}=-\frac3{32}(4xy + xz - 3yz)$

These points correspond to the five lines your conic is tangent to: $$\begin{align}(1:-1:1)&\mapsto x-y+1=0\\
(\frac14:\frac18:1)&\mapsto \frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{8}+1=0\\
(1:0:0)&\mapsto x=0\\
(0:1:0)&\mapsto y=0\\
(0:0:1)&\mapsto z=0\end{align}$$ The fifth being the line at infinity since it's a parabola.

Now the last part is finding the dual conic. The [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve) of a conic is found by taking the adjugate (or inverse if possible) of the corresponding symmetric matrix. $$N=\begin{pmatrix}
     0&2&\frac{1}{2}\\
     2&0&{-\frac{3}{2}}\\
     \frac{1}{2}&{-\frac{3}{2}}&0\end{pmatrix}$$ and taking the inverse of this.

$$N^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
      \frac{3}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&1\\
      \frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{12}&{-\frac{1}{3}}\\
      1&{-\frac{1}{3}}&\frac{4}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

This is the conic in the projective plane (well, I multiplied the equation by $12$ to clear denominators): $9\,x^{2}+6\,x\,y+y^{2}+24\,x\,z-8\,y\,z+16\,z^{2}=0$
. Setting $z=1$ gives the parabola in the plane: $$9x^2+6x y+y^2+24x-8y+16=0.$$

The focus can be read off of the following form of the same equation $$10((x+6/5)^2+(y-2/5)^2-(3y-x)^2/10)=0.$$

[image: five tangents parabola]

Comment: The method applied is somewhat difficult to understand can you explain it mathematically, I mean without coding @jan- Magnus

Comment: @AmanGupta What about this edit?

Comment: Yaa this is easy to understand thanks @Jan-Magnus

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more approach which I believe is very simple:

As you already know that we have two pairs of perpendicular tangents which intersect on the directrix, The equation of directrix is readily known.

Now assume focus to be $(h,k)$. The reflection of the focus over any tangent lies on the directrix which results in that all you have to solve is a system of linear equations to find the focus.

Answer (score 0):

All conics have the form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$.
A parabola has $ac=b^2$.
If it touches $x=0$ then, when you put $x=0$ in, the result is a quadratic in $y$ that is a perfect square.  And so with the other lines.